# Javascript Date.getFullYear() returns 1943 instead of 2013, why?

Tags: javascript, date, gmt, milliseconds

I am a trying to create a Javascript date object from a time in milliseconds computed from GMT0 (or UTC).

I use the following code for a time located in 2013 (as verifiable [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm)):

```
var t = new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
t.setMilliseconds(1383447600000);
```

but when I call the following:

```
alert(t.getFullYear());
alert(t.getUTCFullYear());
```

I am getting 1943... and not 2013!

Why? And how to solve this? Thanks!

The JsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/EVf72/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Use [`setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) instead of [`setMilliseconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds).

**Long Answer**:

The problem is that your starting date is incorrect. The value of `1383447600000` is the number of seconds since epoch `0` (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC), but your starting date is **not** epoch 0! Instead, it is the year `1899`:

```
> var t = new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
> console.log(t.getFullYear());
1899
```

When you then use `setMilliseconds` and provide a range over `999`, it will convert the value into the appropriate numbers of years, days, hours, seconds, and milliseconds and add it to the current date.

`1383447600000` corresponds to a little over 43 years. So you're basically telling JavaScript to add a little over 43 years to 1899, which gives you 1943.

From the documentation for [`setMilliseconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds):

> If you specify a number outside the expected range, the date information in the Date object is updated accordingly. For example, if you specify 1005, the number of seconds is incremented by 1, and 5 is used for the milliseconds.

If you had instead provided the correct starting point to `Date.UTC` so that it matches epoch `0`, you would have received the correct answer:

```
> var t = new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)); //First param is year
> t.setMilliseconds(1383447600000);
> console.log(t.getFullYear());

2013
```

But instead of doing all of that, you can simply use `setTime`:

```
> var t = new Date();
> t.setTime(1383447600000);
> console.log(t.getFullYear());

2013
```

So to recap, the following are functionally equivalent:

```
> var t = new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)); //First param is year
> t.setMilliseconds(1383447600000);
> console.log(t.getFullYear());

2013
```

and

```
> var t = new Date();
> t.setTime(1383447600000);
> console.log(t.getFullYear());

2013
```

But if you are dealing with milliseconds since epoch `0`, you either need to use `setTime`, or make sure that you actually start with epoch `0` (using `Date.UTC`) if you are going to be using `setMilliseconds`.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because `Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` is a large negative number. That gets you a time far in the past. When you call `setMilliseconds()` the semantics are that you're updating the millisecond value on that in-the-past time.  That rolls that time forward, but it's still 70 years in the past because you started far, far back.

The `.setTime()` API on Date instances forces the entire date to be set to the provided timestamp value, overwriting the previous value completely.

Answer (score 0):

Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millisec) returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since midnight of January 1, 1970, according to universal time. You need to fill in the desired date for Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1, ...).